# Android MySql Create and upload image to server with php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I need some help here to put image on an "AD" that user creates. I'm doing it with JSON, Android, PHP and MySql

add_ad.php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //initial query
    $query = "INSERT INTO ads ( ad_title, ad_price, ad_category, ad_description, ad_user, ad_contact ) VALUES ( :title, :price, :category, :description, :email, :mobile ) ";

    //Update query
    $query_params = array(
        ':title' => $_POST['ad_title'],
        ':price' => $_POST['ad_price'],
        ':category' => $_POST['ad_category'],
        ':description' => $_POST['ad_description'],
        ':email' => $_POST['ad_user'],
        ':mobile' => $_POST['ad_contact']
    );

    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Erro base de dados. Impossível adicionar o anúncio.";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Anúncio criado com sucesso! Aguarde aprovação.";
    echo json_encode($response);

} ?>
```

I don't know how to transform this to receive the image from android and save it on the server/database, PLEASE ALSO tell me the type of the field on database.

This is very important, after that I need to send image from my android to this .php and save it on that user.

Thanks, please be aware that I'm new on android, so be brave :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how Android sends the image to this php script, but normally (by web) it's by using the $_FILES server variable. You can read more about file uploads and how to use it here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp.

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
       echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
   } else {

      if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
         echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      } else {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
         // IMAGE UPLOAD SUCCESSFULL, UPDATE DATABASE ROW


      }
    }
  } else {
     echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

After the image is uploaded to the server, you save the filename in your database. If your filename won't be longer than 255 characters you should use a VARCHAR(255) field for this in your database.

Comment: A great answer other than the w3schools link. Can you please remove that [for the sake of humanity](http://www.w3fools.com)?

Comment: Hi, sorry but that is 5% what I need to know.